# Can app crash on one tablet and not on all the others?

Tags: android, crash, galaxy-tab

I made an app and sent it to my client. He has Samsung Galaxy 10inch tablet. He told me that the app is crashing each time when he wants to create a specific entry. So, it looks like logical error and not the error with display.

I've checked the app across all kinds of mobile phones and 480x800 tablet, but there is no crash. He keeps saying that the error exists and that the app crashes each time he repeats special steps.

I was unable to replicate this error on any mobile or tablet device (I do not have galaxy 10 inch tab). I also tried Samsung's 7inch emulator, but no crash occurred.

Is it possible that the crash only happens on Galaxy 10 inch tablet? How to solve this beside buying the real 10 inch device?

Comment: The problem was not in a device itself, but in a `Locale`. That's why we could not replicate the problem. Always have a `Locale` in your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure it's possible...

You could look into [acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) to get some crash report, at least the stack trace of the exception would tell you more about the error...

Comment: it had nothing to a device itself but to a `Locale`. Thanks and sorry for misplacing the problem.